# Rails model design one special member

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: `Game` and `Player`.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Among all the players that belong to a game, only one player is the starting player.

How should I design the model and the db schema?

Could the information about who is the starting player of the game be only in `Game`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that a Game will always have one starting player, and that this will not change even in the future, then you could have a relationship like the following

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has the following attributes
  # starting_player_id:integer:index

  belongs_to :starting_player, class: Player
  has_many :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has the following attributes
  # game_id:integer:index

  has_one :starting_game, foreign_key: :starting_player_id, class: Game
  belongs_to :game
end
```

However, in case if Player-Game is many-to-many, my answer needs to be changed and added with another table

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about teams of people that are players, you might need an extra model to differentiate between  ALL Players and Game Players.  Players could come and go over time but you might want to be able to define certain things, such as which player was the starting player, or which players were at that game at all.

So something like this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_players
  has_many :games, through: :game_players
end


class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_players
  has_many :players, through: :game_players
end

class GamePlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :player

 def starting_player
   return GamePlayer.joins(:game).merge(GamePlayer.starting).first.player
  end
end
```

So GamePlayer would only have a few fields,

```
game_id  (an integer)
player_id  (an integer)
starting  (a boolean)
```

Then you would be able to say

```
@game.starting_player
```

And it would return a single player that was starting

Now if in the event its a team sport you would have a starting player on each side, so you would need to remove the "first" call in the starting_player method, which would give you an array of 2 players.  If you also have an associated Team model on a Player, then you could get both teams

```
@games.starting_player.each do |player|
  # Whatever kind of formulations or front end view code you need
  player.team.name
end
```